Vertical scroll on sub flex element to match the height adjacent element
I have the following snippet with 2 divs in a flex container. The 1st one has 2 sub divs with a fix size (to mock content), the second one has only 1 mock content. Currently the height of the container is equals to the height of the 1 div (and the height of the second div is enlarge to the same height while it could be smaller).
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .content {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 2px red dotted;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="flex: 1;">
            <div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 1;">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>

So now, I would like to force the height of the container (automatically) with the height of the second div (and then force a scroll on the 1st div). How to do it ? Even setting max-height:min-content on the container didn't work.
The result (visually) should be equivalent to this (but not using fixed height)
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .content {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 2px red dotted;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="flex: 1;overflow-y: auto;max-height: 103px;">
            <div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 1;height: fit-content;">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body></html>

From this 
To this 
